# query documentdb using c#

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I want to query DocumentDB using code below, but get exception

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'"

does anyone could give some suggestions? thanks

```
    private const string EndpointUrl = @"myEndpointUrl";
    private const string PrimaryKey = "myKey";
    private DocumentClient client;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);
            var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
  "dbs/myDB/colls/myColl",
  "SELECT c.TestRun.dateFinish FROM c order by c.TestRun.dateFinish desc").ToList();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I found the exception occured when initialize DocumentClient, I am not sure why

Comment: For `TypeInitializationException` you need to check the InnerException for more details